# I cannot get a png image into an image view in android studio

Tags: android, imageview, png

I am trying to display a png image in android studio. When I put it into the image view, it will display in the design view but when I try to run the app it gives me the two following errors.
Error: Invalid file name: must contain only lowercase letters and digits ([a-z0-9_.])
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugRescources'.

Now I know this means it cannot have upper case letters in the file name but there has got to be a way around this right? My file name is the following:
C:\Users\Derek\AndroidStudioProjects\CheckItOut\app\src\main\res\drawable\logo2.PNG

I think the error is the fact that the PNG is in all caps, I don't know why it does this. Any help would be greatly appreciated, in case you couldn't tell; I am very knew to this stuff.

Comment: Just change `.PNG` to .png`?

Answer (score 3):

You need to rename logo2.PNG to logo2.png uppercase letters are not allowed for image resource files

Answer (score 0):

About this i can only say that when calling a drawable in android you should use only the name, without extension (in your case only logo2):

```
 Resources res = getResources();
 Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.logo2);
 //using R.drawable.logo2.png will get you an error
```

If this is not working, maybe using .PNG may be the problem, try changing the resource